# Zephyr Scale integration with Cypress

Tags: integration-testing, cypress, jira-zephyr

we need to integrate Cypress with Zephyr Scale, to execute test cases and put pass/fail resolution.
googled this question we found several solutions, but they are not workable:
https://github.com/valentierro/cypress-zapi-js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-zapi-util
but none of these solutions don't work.
I have an error with mocha functions
[image]
[image]

But I have all dependencies, please help, or maybe you could suggest another library for integration Cypress and Zephyr scale?

Errors:
[image]

Comment: please show the error itself

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I updated the description

Comment: It seems that are not errors but rather warnings from the IDE. Did you try to run the code?

Comment: unfortunately it errors, and when i run the test I get Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'updateJira')

Because this error occurred during a after each hook we are skipping all of the remaining tests.